# How to get objects used in other class in current class using reflection?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jlabel

I am new in the reflection concept. I have JLabel in one class and it is public, in another class  I am getting all public fields and check if it is of type JLabel, I want to change text. For that I am using following code, here I am getting all fields but I cant change the value because the field I am getting from reflection is of type Field I want actual JLabel, if I get it I can change the value of it. Here is my code.

```
Class clazz = LanguageTranslation.class;
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();

for(Field f : fields ) {
    try {
        Class typ = f.getType();
        System.out.println("Type is:"+f.getType()+"\t Name:"+f.getName());
        if(typ.equals(JLabel.class)) {
            /*System.out.println("Field " + f.getName() + " of translation " + languageTranslation + " is a JLabel!");
            typ.setText("Hiiiii");*/
            System.out.println(f);
            typ.setText("Hiiiii");//Setting the text for label but its not working
        }
    } catch ( SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: You need an instance of the `LanguageTranslation` in order to effect change on the fields, you can't "magically" alter the values of fields belonging to a `Class`, they have no state.  As I said yesterday, this is a horribly bad idea.  You have no idea when those fields will be instantiated, when there text might be set or changed.  A better bet would be to use something like [Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/) instead...

Comment: I am 99% sure that whatever you want to do, you do not need reflection.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco then what is best solution, my problem is, A class prepares a GUI, I have a button , When I click on it all labels and buttons translate to french, and i dont know what are fields used in class which prepares a GUI.

Comment: If you have the source code, use [Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `LanguageTranslation` instance to get the `JLabel`

```
LanguageTranslation ltObject=//get it from your app logic
```

Then you can use the method of Field class

```
public Object get(Object obj)
```

You pass the `ltObject` and obtain the `JLabel` instance. After casting you can call `setText()`

UPDATE: After reading commetns. If you have the `LanguageTranslation` instance you can directly access the public fields (including the JLabel)

Comment: How to get JLabel instance by passing `ltObject` object

Comment: @Raghu As StanislavL says, pass the reference to `Field`'s `get` method, it will return an `Object` which you should be able to cast to a `JLabel`...

Comment: @Raghu The problem now is, you must already know about `LanguageTranslation`...so why do we need reflection...

Comment: @MadProgrammer `LanguageTranslation` is a class prepares GUI, I dont knw what are the fields in it. So I want to get fields if it is JLabel, I will translate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ur suggestions realy helped me.

Comment: @Raghu Be prepared for this to blow up in your face, I'm just saying, you have no context of when things are initialised or changed

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LanguageTranslation {

public JLabel test;

public LanguageTranslation() {
    test = new JLabel();
    test.setText("Original");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LanguageTranslation obj = new LanguageTranslation();
    System.out.println(obj.test.getText());

    Class clazz = LanguageTranslation.class;
    Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        try {
            Class typ = f.getType();
            System.out.println("Type is:" + f.getType() + "\t Name:" + f.getName());
            if (typ.equals(JLabel.class)) {
                System.out.println(f);
                try {
                    Method m = typ.getMethod("setText", String.class);
                    System.out.println(m);
                    m.invoke(obj.test, "Changed Value");
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(obj.test.getText());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you've run this, cause `f` isn't an instance of an object....basically what you're saying is `Class.setText("Hiii")`...pretty sure that won't work...

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`

Comment: Nope, `obj` is now an instance of `LanguageTranslation`, but you're trying to interact with the `Field`, it is unlikely that `LanguageTranslation` has a `setText` method, and if it does, it won't do what the OP is expecting - that is, it will change the wrong value

Comment: What happens if you have more than one `JLabel` field?  You're assuming a reference...it kind of defeats the purpose of using reflection, I could reduce your entire code to `obj.test.setText(...)` and forget about all the reflection mess...

Comment: It can. Your code invokes `setText` n times on `obj.test` and doesn't do anything useful with other fields of `obj`, which doesn't make a lot of sense. Also, you didn't provide any explanation on why your code works (probably because it doesn't). Stackoverflow is Q&A site, not a source code repository/debugging portal.

Answer (score -2):

```
 typ.setText("Hiiiii");
```

instead of above line try below line

```
f.setText("Hiiiii");
```

Comment: `f` is an instance of `Field`, when did `Field` get a `setText` method?